# Interpreting the value of TEXT as a part of a query?

Tags: mysql

Consider this example below in MySQL.

```
DECLARE myText TEXT;
SET myText = "myColumn";

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myText = "myValue";
```

In the above scenario, it wouldn't select any columns, because the value of myText is never "myValue". However, what I really want to do is to interpret the value of myText as a part of the query, so that the final query that it executes is:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn = "myValue";
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)

```
SET @myText = "myColumn";
SET @s = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ', @myText, ' = "myValue" ');
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @s;
EXECUTE stmt1;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
```